# How to add ClientCeritifcates, The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, messagecontract

I'm getting the follwing error when calling a method from a auto-generated web service proxy class:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233087   Message=The HTTP request was forbidden with
>   client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>       Server stack trace: 
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException,
>   HttpChannelFactory'1 factory)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory'1 factory,
>   WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory'1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>       Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>          at RPS.LoteNFe.LoteNFeSoap.TesteEnvioLoteRPS(TesteEnvioLoteRPSRequest
>   request)
>          at RPS.LoteNFe.LoteNFeSoapClient.RPS.LoteNFe.LoteNFeSoap.TesteEnvioLoteRPS(TesteEnvioLoteRPSRequest
>   request) in c:\Users\Marcelo\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\RPS\RPS\Service References\LoteNFe\Reference.cs:line 560
>          at RPS.LoteNFe.LoteNFeSoapClient.TesteEnvioLoteRPS(Int32 VersaoSchema, String MensagemXML) in c:\Users\Marcelo\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2015\Projects\RPS\RPS\Service
>   References\LoteNFe\Reference.cs:line 567
>          at RPS.Assinador.button5_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Marcelo\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\RPS\RPS\Assinador.cs:line 76
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at RPS.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Marcelo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RPS\RPS\Program.cs:line 19
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: System.Net.WebException
>          HResult=-2146233079
>          Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
>          Source=System
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory'1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          InnerException:

This is how a call it

```
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2();
X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection collection = ((X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates).Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
X509Certificate2Collection collection1 = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(collection, "Certificados disponiveis", "Selecione o certificado", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
x509Certificate = collection1[0];

LoteNFeSoapClient loteNFe = new LoteNFeSoapClient();
loteNFe.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(x509Certificate.Subject, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My);
Retorno.Text = loteNFe.TesteEnvioLoteRPS(1, Assinado.Text);
```

How I added this web service reference:

In MS Visual Studio 2013 community, `Project > Add > Service Reference`:

[Service Reference window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNSAE.png)

[Service Reference advanced settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEC5b.png)

Obs: Those are default configs. This a municipal gorvernment webservice used to send eletronic invoices of transportation or logistics services provided.

Ive read somewhere that is necessary to add a certificate like:

```
LoteNFeSoapClient loteNFe = new LoteNFeSoapClient();
loteNFe.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
```

But its not possible because:

1. This auto-generated webservice class doesnt inherit from an class
   that has this method `ClientCertificates.Add()` like `HttpWebClientProtocol` class for example.
2. `LoteNFeSoapClient()` class is already inheriting from a
   interface that makes the messagecontract to match values between
   request and response.
3. In c# a class can't have multiple base classes.

So, what could be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I just generated the webservice proxy class via command line using wsdl.exe, this class now inherits from `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol`, so I can add the certificate using

```
LoteNFe loteNFe = new LoteNFe();
loteNFe.ClientCertificates.Add(x509Certificate);
```

Note: The class generated via command line is completely different from the one generated using VS2013 UI.